# DRW errorHandler always returns "Error" as the error message instead of a real message

Tags: java, javascript, struts, dwr

```
FiltersManager.getAllServices({
                callback : updateServiceFilter,
                errorHandler : function(message) {
                    alert(message);
                }
          });
```

When an error occures, in the backend i am throwing an exception, but the error message always says "Error" when alerted

Is there some setting I need to turn on?

Comment: Did you set the handler first? "dwr.engine.setErrorHandler(handler);"

Comment: @AsierAranbarri no I haven't and when I tried just now there was a javascript error that "handler" was undefined

Answer (score 2):

### From DWR guide:

When there is no exception converter specified for an exception, the exception object passed to the client looks like this:

```
{
  javaClassName:'java.lang.Throwable',
  message:'Error'
}
```

You can enable a more verbose exception handler with the following in dwr.xml:

```
<convert match="java.lang.Exception" converter="exception"/>
```

By default, this will attempt to convert everything that is part of the exception, so the converted exception might look like this:

```
{ 
  javaClassName:'org.xml.sax.SAXParseException',
  lineNumber:42,
  publicId:'somePublicId',
  message:'Missing >'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the second argument for [DWR's errorHandler](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/errors.html)?

```
errorHandler:function(errorString, exception) {
    console.log(exception);
}
```